# How spring boot is controlling jdbc connection? Unable to get jdbc connection issue is coming frequently

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, database-connection, connection-pooling

I m working in a medium size application where around 50 services are there , using springboot and jpa. Unable to get jdbc connection error comes whenever i try to run a multi threading service. I have set my db connection config as

Please suggest the correct configuration .Or please let me know how springboot-jpa controls connection ? When it is getting released.
In code we are not doing any kinda connection handling.
All are done from framework level.

Comment: My connection params

spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=100
spring.datasource.initialSize=25  
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=10
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=10000

Comment: Your question does not conform to a [MCVE] as per SO standards. try to improve it to get more attention and avoid close votes.